# Why does android studio not show build output warnings?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, warnings

Android studio used to show warnings in build output when building project, but now it doesn't.
For my other projects it still is showing the warnings, but for this specific project the warnings are not displayed.
[Warnings not showing for this specific project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvkeX.png)

[But for other projects warning are displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8EKW.png)

I don't wanna change the gradle files and lint or other parameters in the project, because my colleagues are using the same project settings and they are getting the warnings that I used to get.

I set --warning-mode all in command line but did not work.
I also cleaned the project, invalidated cache and restarted android studio, installed newer version of android studio, Hedgehog.
I also copied the project to another location and opened it again but that didn't work either.